# AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.resizable(False, False)


def nameLength(event):
    str(input)
    length = input.split()
    length1 = len(garums)

    myLabel = Label(root, text=length1.get()).pack( )

choice = ("Word count", "Delete symbol", "Change 1st word with last word")

options = StringVar()
options.set("Choose an option")

input = Entry(root)
input.pack()



menu = OptionMenu(root, options, *choice, command=nameLength)
menu.pack(pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

When I run my code, I tend to get an error saying that
AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'split'

I've tried googling it and noone seems to have the same exact problem as I do.
Would appreciate if someone would help or explain!

Comment: `Entry` is a widget. `input` is an instance of `Entry` class. There is no method `.split` in this class. What `str(input)` is supposed to do?

Comment: @Corralien it is supposed to convert it to a string. Tried googling about the problem and some websites said to convert the input into a string and that would make the error disappear.

Comment: In general it is adviced not to use built-in name for variables, like you did for `input`. Now, it seems you're trying to call `split` on your `input` variable which is not a `string` but a `Entry` object, so it's normal that it does not work. Maybe try doing `input = str(input)` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is an instance of an `Entry` object. Like the error says, it has no method `split`. Since it is an `Entry` object, it is *not* a string object. You must use methods to get strings into and out of `Entry` objects.

```
input_value = input.get()
length = input_value.split()
```